# save information in a file but no information is saved?

Tags: python, file

I need to save information to later in my code. I have never done this before since I a new to this. I am trying to figure it out with dummy information before saving the real information.
However, I am not getting any errors with this code beneath.

```
def skriv_till_doc():
    
    f = open('pos.txt', 'w')
    f.write('Now the file has more content!')
    f.close()
    print('klar')
```

The issue is that the text that is written in `f.write` does not show in the pos.txt file

the file of this code and the pos.txt file is in the same folder. `klar` is also shown in the terminal.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: i am using Windows 11.

Comment: Might be obvious, but do you actually **call** this function? Is the `"klar"` printed?

Comment: yes klar is printed in terminal, sorry i missed that in the text above.

Comment: Then the "pos.txt" file will contain the line written. Have you looked in the right location for the file? Have you tried deleting the file first, then looking to see it created by your program?

Comment: what the!!!??
i did delete and now i went back one step in folders and there is the file with this information. how come that the txt file is one step above the codefile and not in the same map?

Comment: When you create files in `python` with a bare name like you have, the folder it is created in is where 'you' are when you run the program and not where your program file is.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Ransomware Protection** might be blocking **Python** from making changes to the working directory.

You need to allow **Python** through **Controlled Folder Access**.

> Go to Windows Security -> Virus & threat protection -> Ransomware
> Protection -> Manage Ransomware Protection -> Controlled folder access
> -> Allow an app through Controlled folder access -> Add an allowed app -> Recently blocked apps -> python.exe

I hope this helps.